# How to install MariaDB-Client on CentOS 8? It says 'unable to find a match'

Tags: centos, yum, mariadb

**Objective:** Installing client only of MariaDB for command line testing of working connection webserver <>  external server.

There are numerous tutorials to be found which describe MariaDB installation, often including installation of a `MariaDB-Client` package. I've added the repository to `/etc/yum.repos.d` but still `yum install mariadb-client` fails, stating that

```
No match for argument: mariadb-client
Error: Unable to find a match: mariadb-client
```

I can, however, install the `mariadb-server` package just fine and I can on command line verify my db connection - but that's overkill, installing a full server to get client functionality.

How do I accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such package. If you need to install the `mysql` utility, please run `sudo dnf install mariadb`.

In the future, you could do this:

```bsh
# dnf whatprovides '*bin/mysql'
community-mysql-8.0.21-11.fc33.x86_64 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Other       : *bin/mysql

community-mysql-8.0.23-1.fc33.x86_64 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Other       : *bin/mysql

mariadb-3:10.4.14-2.fc33.x86_64 : A very fast and robust SQL database server
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Other       : *bin/mysql

mariadb-3:10.4.17-1.fc33.x86_64 : A very fast and robust SQL database server
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Other       : *bin/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install MariaDB-client following the instructions in [the official documentation](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-install-mariadb-on-rhel8-centos8/):

```
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup
sudo ./mariadb_repo_setup
```

Use `dnf` or `yum`:

```
sudo yum install perl-DBI libaio libsepol lsof boost-program-options
sudo yum install --repo="mariadb-main" MariaDB-client
```

Comment: it tells me "no such option --repo"